# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15.3 (from ludwig)

Tags: linux, tensorflow, debian, ludwig

So i am aiming to install Ludwig for experimentation but i didn't found any solution on the internet to this issue [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u2GD.png)

[screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u2GD.png)

i am using windows subsytem for linux (debian)

Answer (score 0):

Your python version is probably unsupported by tensorflow 1.15.3. I ran into the same issue trying to install with python 3.8.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34302

Answer (score 0):

When I compiled Ludwig from GitHub source, there were a lot of dependencies to patch. I experienced the same error message and I gave up solving it.

I retried with clean installation from the very beginning, I managed to install Ludwig successfully on Google Cloud - Debian 9 VM.

Now I redo the steps on Oracle Cloud - Ubuntu 20.04 VM.

**Steps:**

Ensure the following dependencies are ready, which I consolidate from various sources.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev curl libbz2-dev lzma liblzma-dev python3-tk
```

Clean install Python 3.6. I choose to use older Python 3.6 to execute Ludwig, because Ludwig is using the old Tensorflow 1.15.3. I reserve Python 3.7 and 3.8 environment for other newer Python projects, for example Tensorflow 2.

```
# Simply use a temporary working folder.
$ cd /tmp

# Download the newest Python3.6 source.
$ curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.12/Python-3.6.12.tgz
$ tar -xzvf Python-3.6.12.tgz
$ cd Python-3.6.12

# --prefix=/usr/local ensures the newly installed Python3.6 does not mess up with the default Python executables in the OS. This is specially warned in Google Cloud.
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-optimizations
$ sudo make altinstall
$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.12

# Upgrade pip and virtualenv
$ sudo python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip
$ sudo python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Prepare the virtual environment for Ludwig.
Reference https://ludwig-ai.github.io/ludwig-docs/getting_started/#installation.

```
# Go back to home.
$ cd

# Create a Working directory.
$ mkdir Works
$ cd Works

# Initialize a virtual environment with Python3.6
$ virtualenv -p python3.6 ludwig
$ source ludwig/bin/activate

# Install Ludwig
$ pip install ludwig
```

You can see every dependencies are taken care of and Ludwig is ready to use.

```
$ pip list
Package              Version
-------------------- -------
... ...
ludwig               0.2.2.8
...
tensorflow           1.15.3
...

# Execute Ludwig
$ ludwig
```